# saving a dataframe to csv file (python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to restructure the way my precipitations' data is being organized in an excel file. To do this, I've written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('El Jem_Souassi.xlsx', sheetname=None, header=None)
data=df["El Jem"]

T=[]
for column in range(1,56):
    liste=data[column].tolist()
    for row in range(1,len(liste)):
        liste[row]=str(liste[row])
        if liste[row]!='nan':
            T.append(liste[row])

result=pd.DataFrame(T)
result
```

This code works fine and through Jupyter I can see that the result is good
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gttE6.jpg)

However, I am facing a problem when attempting to save this dataframe to a csv file.

```
 result.to_csv("output.csv")
```

The resulting file contains the vertical index column and it seems I am unable to call for a specific cell.

(Hopefully, someone can help me with this problem)
Many thanks !!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's all in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

You are interested in skipping the index column, so do:

`result.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)`

If you also want to skip the header add:

`result.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, header=False)`

---

I don't know how your input data looks like (it is a good idea to make it available in your question). But note that currently you can obtain the same results just by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0]*16)
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I am still new (so I can't upvote ur answer) but thanks a lot for the help. That solved my problem.

Comment: @farhat sure! You can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark near the answer, I'd be obliged :) NB: there might be a much easier way of doing what you want to your data, but it'd be easier to help if you show as how they look like (preferably not through a screenshot).

Comment: Thanks again ^^ (for both the advice and the tip about the green checkmark)

Comment: @jjj If it gets converted to csv, where does this file save? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jsl5703 what do you mean? You can specify a path yourself. If you won't it'll be in the dir you started python in